# How to find all invalid timezones stored in postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone

In our app, we store the timezone of users in the db with the user record.
However, somehow, we ended up with invalid timezones (as far as postgres concerned). Probably, because original values a coming from a different source...

Now, when we are trying to use the timezone in one of the queries, for example:

```
select current_time, u.*
from users u
where extract(hour from (current_time at time zone u.time_zone)) = 8
```

We are getting error like:

> ERROR:  time zone "US/Pacific-New" not recognized

What is the best way to deal with this issue? How can I identify all the records that have invalid timezone in them?

Comment: Shouldn't they all have a match in pg_timezone_names table? If they don't would you want to try and fuzzy match?

Comment: @Slumdog Well, ideally, I want to fix the records into something that postgres understands.

Comment: Sounds like a left join against pg_timezone_names would be a good start though, to find the broken rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I identify all the records that have invalid timezone in them?

This is one way

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM   users u 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   pg_timezone_names tz 
                   WHERE  tz.NAME = u.time_zone);
```